# Cassandra: All host(s) tried for query failed

Tags: node.js, cassandra, datagrip

I have run

`sudo docker run --name cassandraDB --network cassandraDB -d cassandra:3`

and I can connect to Cassandra from cqlsh:

`sudo docker run -it --network cassandraDB --rm cassandra cqlsh cassandraDB`

But, I can not connect to Cassandra from DataGrip and node.js

Comment: what error node.js is showing?

Comment: It is usually a docker networking issue, are you using Mac, Windows or Linux? Docker Desktop?
There should be more information in the error message, could you post it also.

Answer (score 0):

To connect with DataGrip you need to expose port to connect via JDBC.
Default Cassandra port is `9042`.

Additionally, read [DataGrip documentation about Apache Cassandra connection](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/datagrip/connecting-to-a-database.html#connect-to-cassandra-database)